# "getter" keyword in @property declaration in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

I noticed some code example in Apple's documentation shows the following style when declaring the property:

```
@property (nonatomic, getter=isActivated) BOOL activated;
```

I understand it allows you to specify a certain name for your getter method. I'd like to know what is the reason and advantage to use this style.

Will I be able to use the dot notation to get the value (e.g. BOOL aBool = someObject.isActivated)? Or should I use
`[someObject            isActivated];` 
to access the property? Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, the `getter` keyword only changes the method name. The idea is that you'll access the property just like a variable:

```
if (self.activated) { ... }
self.activated = YES;
```

But when you're **sending a message** to the object, it's readable code: `if ([self isActivated]) { ... }`.

Answer (score 6):

Kind of the latter. You don’t have to use the method—calling `someObject.activated` will still work—but it lets you improve the semantics of your class’s interface. A method called `-activated` could return the value of the ivar `activated`, or it could do something more esoteric (like activating the object); `isActivated` clearly returns a Boolean value for whether or not the object is “activated”.