# ObjC: proper use of property and synthesize?

Tags: objective-c, clang

Does anyone know why this code is running into compilation errors?  I'm compiling it on Catalina using clang.  I posted a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61979096/objc-using-property-and-synthesize-correctly) but that was when I was trying to compile using clang on Linux.  I thought getA and setA are auto-generated by synthesize.  Thanks!

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface A: NSObject

@property int a;

@end

@implementation A
{
    int a;
}
@synthesize a;

@end

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
  @autoreleasepool {
    A *a = [[A alloc] init];

    [a setA:99];
    int v = [a getA];
    NSLog (@" %d\n", v);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation:

```
$ clang -framework Foundation otest0.m -o hello
otest0.m:23:16: warning: instance method '-getA' not found (return type defaults
      to 'id') [-Wobjc-method-access]
    int v = [a getA];
               ^~~~
otest0.m:3:12: note: receiver is instance of class declared here
@interface A: NSObject
           ^
otest0.m:23:9: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing
      'int' with an expression of type 'id' [-Wint-conversion]
    int v = [a getA];
        ^   ~~~~~~~~
2 warnings generated.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getter/setter pair is synthesized as

```
-(int)a;
-(void)setA:(int)val;
```

So you need:

```
int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
  @autoreleasepool {
    A *a = [[A alloc] init];

    [a setA:99];
    int v = [a a];
    NSLog (@" %d\n", v);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this solved the problem.  I'm confused why the getter wasn't synthesized as getA to correspond with setA.

Comment: There is some notation to make it do that in the property declaration but this form is the default style.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210937/getter-keyword-in-property-declaration-in-objective-c

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, I'm surprised apple didn't stick with setX getX, and chose setX, x.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a property with name `a` produces a getter with name `a`, not `getA`.
This is what the first warning is about: "instance method '-getA' not found"

Answer (score -2):

This works on my system (macOS):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface A: NSObject

@property int a;

@end

@implementation A {
  int a;
}
@synthesize a;

-(int) getMyValue {
return a;
}

@end

int main () {
  @autoreleasepool {
    A *a = [[A alloc] init];
   [a setA:99];
   NSLog (@"value = %d", [a getMyValue]);
 }
  return 0;
}
```

If file is saved as synth.m the terminal command is: clang synth.m -framework Foundation -o synth && ./synth

Comment: I can confirm you code works.  Now, shouldn't synthesize create two methods getA and setA?  I try changing getMyValue to getA and that results in compilation errors.  Do you observe this as well? Thanks

Comment: If you change the method to -(int)getA and then use [a getA] in the main to retrieve it, it should compile without error.

Comment: I think you're expecting there to be a "get" for every "set", when in fact objc does not use the word "get" for the getter, only "set" for the setter.

Comment: every where I'm reading says that synthesize automatically creates a getter and/or setter method.  So you're saying it only creates a setter?  Thanks

Comment: No, it creates both, but you can only use "set" for the setter.  The creators of objc did not use "get" for the getter.  According to Kochan in ''Programming in Objective-C": methods that set the values of instance variables are often collectively referred to as setters, and methods used to retrieve the values of instance variables are called getters.